# Support Annotation @StringDef, @IntDef declaration standards?

Tags: android, android-studio, annotations, android-support-library

@StringDef, @IntDef etc has made life much simpler and good alternatives to using enums. 
Typically we see that these are defined as follows:

```
@IntDef({NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD, NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST, NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
public @interface NavigationMode {}

public static final int NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD = 0;
public static final int NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST = 1;
public static final int NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS = 2;
....
```

Would there be any issue if one was to define these inside of the annotation itself. eg:

```
@IntDef({NavigationMode.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD, NavigationMode.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST, NavigationMode.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
public @interface NavigationMode {
  int NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD = 0;
  int NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST = 1;
  int NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS = 2;
}
....
```

This comes in handy when these def annotation is defined separately so it could be used across modules.

Comment: Whats's difference between these two different declarations?

Answer (score 1):

I am using `@IntDef` notoriously. It's awesome, especially since Android Studio 2.0 can work correctly with this annotation and `switch` statement.

---

I am usually using this pattern:

```
public static final class NavigationMode {

    @IntDef({NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD, NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST, NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS})
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
    public @interface Value {
    }

    public static final int NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD = 0;
    public static final int NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST = 1;
    public static final int NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS = 2;

    // Suppress default constructor for noninstantiability
    private NavigationMode() {
        throw new AssertionError();
    }
}
```

Then I can refer to the value through `NavigationMode.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD` and the annotation is `@NavigationMode.Value` with a bit simpler `@IntDef` definition (without `NavigationMode.` prefixes).

[image]

But I must say... I like your second approach really much!

```
@IntDef({NavigationMode.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD, NavigationMode.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST, NavigationMode.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
public @interface NavigationMode {
    int NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD = 0;
    int NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST = 1;
    int NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS = 2;
}
```

I might even switch to it. Although I'm not a big fan of the way Android Studio colors it then:

[image]

I don't think there should be any issues with values defined this way.

Comment: I agree, I am using IntDef, StringDef  a lot and avoiding enum like a plague. I kind of liked explicitly defining it, as I mentioned in my OP. I don't know why I did not come across anyone using it like I pointed out.

Comment: What's difference between two

Comment: Between what exactly?